# Doing part of my PhD remotely in Europe while working full time?

Tags: phd, united-states, europe, remote-work

my US company offered me the prospect of doing my PhD (in public health, public policy, international development or something similar) at a European university while retaining my employment. They would also pay for the PhD. My thesis would be based on a research project I was already going to pursue in my work. I already have a Masters in Economics. Would a university be okay if I only worked out of the university for the first and the 2nd and 3rd year was finishing my research in the USA? Thanks!

Comment: Does the company already have in mind a particular university (and advisor), perhaps in place from on-going joint research? Has somebody from the company done this before at that university?

Comment: The company does have a relationship with a couple of universities there, but I was wondering if I would be able apply to other universities.

Comment: I suspect that your company has some specific ideas, although if they didn't bring that up when discussing with you its kind of odd. I would have thought something more like your manager having a meeting with you and saying "Goldy, would you like to go to Oxford to work on a PhD with Prof. BigName?" I would get clarification from management on what the company would, and would not, support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to check that with both the university and with any supervisor/advisor you would have. I'm pretty sure that such relationships do occur, even if not common. But being less the norm, you need to work out the details.

In some ways the supervisor might be the bigger block than the university. It might take a trip to Europe to finalize any such arrangements. But you first need to determine if they would even consider such a situation. The answers will vary.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like you think this is not out of realm of possibility. I am okay with mid-tier universities, so not sure where to start processing of narrowing down list of schools. The process is very different in North America, that I am more aware of.